# Symfony2: Two forms with a single controller (how to distinguish them with the name of the submit button)

Tags: php, post, button, symfony

I have two forms : authorEdit and author Create. Those two forms are managed in a single controller. Each form has a submit button and the names of those buttons are not the same.

How can I check in my controller which form am I using regarding the submit button name?

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use 2 different actions and then call a shared method.

```
/**
 * ...
 */
public function createAction()
{
    return $this->processForm('create');
}

/**
 * ...
 */
public function editAction()
{
    return $this->processForm('edit');
}

private function processForm($action)
{
    // ...
    return array(/* ... */);
}
```

Comment: thank you. I like the idea, but that means that I have to create two separate routes etc ?

Comment: This is agood idea. You could also use a parameter (query string?) to decide in what situation you are

Answer (score 3):

There is also a solution if you want to use only one route:

If the forms you are using have different names (so you have overwritten the getName() function), you can check with

```
$this->getRequest()->get('yourFormName'))
```

if one form was transmitted.

So in your case it would look like:

```
if($this->getRequest()->get('authorEdit')) {
    //
} elseif($this->getRequest()->get('authorCreate')) {
    //
}
```